Row-Level Locking for Concurrent Processing in Java
I have a table called message where I process messages received over time. I am running a Java Spring Boot application deployed across multiple instances and JVMs. When a message with a specific id is picked for processing, I set its status to processing. I want to ensure that no other instance or thread picks up the same rows while they are being processed. Essentially, I need to lock the rows with the same id so that only one instance can process them at a time.
Other instances should wait if the rows are in the processing state and retry after the processing is completed. The goal is to make other instances wait while the processing state is active and allow them to process the message only after the status changes.
I am using Java JPA and Hibernate, and I do not have shared caching between the instances. Is there a way to achieve this using pessimistic locking?
Table structure example:



id
message
status
time




x
hello
processing
11-12-24:11:08:09Z


x
boy
processing
12-12-24:11:08:09Z


y
hi
completed
12-12-24:11:08:09Z


z
me
initial
12-12-24:11:08:09Z




I would probably just optimistically lock on the change to the status column.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258295/how-to-acquired-a-lock-at-database-row-level-using-in-spring-boot-and-hibernate may help
